# cordova android compile failure

Tags: android, cordova

I've been fighting with this all week and am at my wits end.

I have a Cordova project.  It runs on Android and iPhone.

The iPhone project builds and runs.

The android project has the following error:

```
-compile:
  [javac] Compiling 9 source files to /Users/markj/myProj/platforms/android/ant-build/classes
  [javac] warning: [options] source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
  [javac] warning: [options] target value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
  [javac] warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
  [javac] /Users/markj/myProj/platforms/android/src/org/apache/cordova/inappbrowser/InAppBrowser.java:56: error: cannot find symbol
  [javac] import org.apache.cordova.CordovaHttpAuthHandler;
  [javac]                          ^
```

I thought it was related to the version of cordova - i had recently upgraded to v6, so I downgraded to v3 - the version i did the bulk of the development on.

the problem still continued.

i thought my plugins were the wrong version so i downgraded them to the original versions i used with cordova v3.

the problem still continued.

i updated my android tools and made sure the target sdk matched what i had used during development (21)

and, say it with me, the problem still continued.

google says its related to the the version of cordova and the version of android but i am unclear what the correct versions are.

can anyone help?

Comment: could you try removing and adding android platform after updating to latest Cordova version once.

Comment: Sounds really cordova/android like to me:)) What s on /inappbrowser/InAppBrowser.java:56? Is it not looking for a SDK version higher than the version it compiles with (hence it cannot know yet it exists)?